# Dropwizard custom ExceptionMapper for javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, exception, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard and would like to create a custom ExceptionMapper to handle `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`. I've created a customer mapper:

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        return Response.status(500)
                .entity(exception.getMessage())
                .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and configured it in my Dropwizard app:

```
@Override
public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
    ServerFactory serverFactory = configuration.getServerFactory();
    if (serverFactory instanceof AbstractServerFactory) {
        ((AbstractServerFactory) serverFactory).setRegisterDefaultExceptionMappers(false);
    }

    environment.jersey().register(new MyExceptionMapper());
}
```

When a resource/controller throws a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` exception it's not handled by my custom mapper, instead it goes through `org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationExceptionMapper` which returns a 400 which is not what I want.

Is it possible to override/remove Jersey's mapper? I would have thought setting `setRegisterDefaultExceptionMappers(false);` would do the trick but it seems that it doesn't.

Comment: _"I'm using Dropwizard and would like to create a custom ExceptionMapper to handle javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException"_ - Then why are you using `Exception` type and not `ConstraintViolationException`?

Comment: Changing to the specific `ConstraintViolationException` seems to works. I used `Exception` as a catch-all but seems like it doesn't work. Using `Throwable` doesn't work either. Is it possible to create a catch all ExceptionMapper that would catch `ConstraintViolationException`?

Comment: No unless you can figure out how to disable the default mapper. With two mappers, the mapper with the exception type closest the actual exception type will be used.